# Is basis for a Matrix field unique?

Tags: tensor-products

In general, when expressing a Matrix field, Q, in terms of it's local and dual basis (the tensor product between a a row vector and column vector), is such basis unique or are there infinitely many possible basis?

Comment: What is a matrix field?  I have never heard that term before, and I know a fair bit of linear algebra.  Can you include a specific example? I know what a dual basis is, relative to an initial choice of basis, but I've never heard of a local basis.

Comment: A matrix field is a rank 2 tensor.